# Summing up a list of integer arrays using threads for each array in C# Console application

Tags: c#, arrays, multithreading

I have a List of int arrays. The list can be from 1 to 4 arrays.
I want to know how do i go about summing each array with individual threads and 
placing the summed values into a new int array.

Comment: "summed value" or "summed values" ?  Makes a difference. It wouldn't hurt to provide a code outline.

Comment: Sorry I ment summed values

Comment: Never too late to edit the question.

Comment: Thanks any chance you can help with the following. I was hoping for a standardized threading method if possible

Comment: You already have those answers. The one form Prot1990 will work, `result[i]` is thread-safe. Don't use bare Threads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the order of the new array is not important here you have a example

```
          List<int[]> arraysList = new List<int[]>();
        arraysList.Add(new int[] { 2, 3, 5 });
        arraysList.Add(new int[] { 2, 3, 5, 9, 123, 5 });
        arraysList.Add(new int[] { 3 });
        arraysList.Add(new int[] { 9,8 });




        ConcurrentBag<int> SummedValueOfEveryArray = new ConcurrentBag<int>();
        Parallel.ForEach(arraysList, array =>
        {
            SummedValueOfEveryArray.Add(array.Sum());
        });

        //Your result
        var result = SummedValueOfEveryArray.ToArray<int>();
        //The sum of all arrays
        var totalSum = SummedValueOfEveryArray.Sum();
```

Comment: Thanks this works. I was hoping for a standardized threading method if possible.

Comment: @RyanRichard What do you mean with "Standardized thearding method"?
Here there is one theard for every array (not matter if there are 4 or 4000)

PS: the prof1990 answer is nice because the order in the final array it keeps

Answer (score 2):

This code will do what you ask. One side note however, this only parallelizes when .Net feels it could improve performance.

```
List<int[]> intlist = new List<int[]>();
int[] result = intlist.AsParallel().Select(arr => arr.Sum()).ToArray();
```

Given 1 to 4 arrays it may be that .Net never sees the point of parallelizing. But if you absolutely must you can force parallelization by using Parallel.For as shown below.

```
List<int[]> intlist = new List<int[]>();
int[] result = new int[intlist.Count];
Parallel.For(0, intlist.Count, i => 
{
    result[i] = intlist[i].Sum();
});
```

Comment: "Given 1 to 4 arrays there is very little point .." - is very wrong. The expected gain solely depends on the length of those arrays.